# How to avoid the space in specified location when build my source using c#?

Tags: c#

I have tried to build a set of project file using c# code like as below code

```
string workingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727";
string arguments = string.Format("/c MSBuild {0} /p:Configuration=Release  /t:rebuild /p:OutDir={1}", fileName);
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", arguments);
```

But some project files having spaces in the path location. so build can be failed also tried to replace the spaces by `%20` it is also not working.

so please suggest me a better solution to solve this.

Comment: Use quotation marks.

Comment: Escape path with quotes ("c:\path with spaces\...").

Comment: already i am using folder name in quotation like 'fileName=@"D:\filter.sln";'

Comment: your `string.Format` has not enough arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an argument to your `String.Format()`.
It also looks like you should use escaped quotes `\"` to ensure your paths are quoted, like so:

```
string workingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727";
string arguments = string.Format("/c MSBuild \"{0}\" /p:Configuration=Release /t:rebuild /p:OutDir=\"{1}\"", fileName, workingDirectory);
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", arguments);
```

Answer (score 2):

Three ways to solve the spacing problem to command prompt:

```
cd "/path/path/path/A Folder/file"
cd '/path/path/path/A Folder/file'
cd /path/path/path/A\ Folder/file
```

Read the answer from `@Benoit`: https://askubuntu.com/a/530581

In C#,

1) Simply add `"` at the beginning and the end

2) Simply add `'` at the beginning and the end

3) you could make use of `string.Replace()` to add `\` in front of the space.